# How to convert one-to-one jpa mapping to one-to-one hbm.xml mapping?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a one to one relationship between two entities (lets say Book.java and Author.java):

```
@Table(name = "BOOK")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seqBook", allocationSize = 0, sequenceName = "SEQ_BOOK")
@Entity
class Book implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "BOOK_ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seqBook")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "BOOK_NAME")
private Long name;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "book", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
private Author author;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Long getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(Long name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Author getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public void setAuthor(Author author) {
    this.author = author;
}
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "AUTHOR")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seqAuthor", allocationSize = 0, sequenceName = "SEQ_AUTHOR")
class Author implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "AUTHOR_ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seqAuthor")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "AUTHOR_NAME")
private Long name;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
@JoinColumn(name = "BOOK_ID", nullable = false)
private Book book;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Book getBook() {
    return book;
}

public void setBook(Book book) {
    this.book = book;
}

public Long getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(Long name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

as you can see they are mapped by JPA annotations and its working fine. in the database table I just have the BOOK_ID as foreign key in the AUTHOR table.
Now I want to move the mapping to hbm.xml file so I created Book.hbm.xml and Author.hbm.xml and removed the annotations from java classes:

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.abc" default-access="field">
<class
        name="com.abc.book"
        table="BOOK">
    <id name="id" column="BOOK_ID">
        <generator class="native">
            <param name="sequence_name">SEQ_BOOK</param>
        </generator>
    </id>

    <property
            name="name"
            column="BOOK_NAME"/>

    <one-to-one
            name="author"
            class="Author"
            lazy="false"
            fetch="join"
            cascade="all"
            constrained="true"/>

</class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<hibernate-mapping package="com.abc" default-access="field">

<class
    name="com.abc.author"
    table="AUTHOR">
    <id name="id" column="AUTHOR_ID">
        <generator class="native">
            <param name="sequence_name">SEQ_AUTHOR</param>
        </generator>
    </id>

    <property
        name="name"
        column="AUTHOR_NAME"/>

    <one-to-one
        name="book"
        class="Book"
        cascade="all"/>

</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

But I am getting HibernateObjectRetrievalFailureException and I have tried different attributes for One-To-One tag in the xml file. Does anybody now what is the correct way to do this kind of mapping in hbm.xml files?

Comment: JPA uses `orm.xml` not some Hibernate specific relic

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto I want to be able to map the entities to two different schemas in the hbm.xml after I get the hibernate mapping worked.

Comment: As Hibernate is a JPA implementation, it can use JPA annotations, should use that... You cannot map a single entity to 2 different shcemas/tables/etc...

Comment: You can use one `orm.xml` with one persistence unit, and a different `orm.xml` with another persistence unit. So, of course you can map an entity to multiple schemas (but with **different** EMFs)